# Regex, validator Contraint for domino user name

Tags: regex, xpages, xpages-ssjs

[image]

[image]

My understanding for the error, does it means not allow special character for Username?

If i want to use validator Constraint Regex Formula:

```
message = Please key in the valid name.
regex = ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Error message : It always give me, Please key in the valid name.

sample Name that i wish to be pass is

Result that **Pass** :

```
NURIASHA BINTI ABD HALIM
```

Result that **Fail** :

```
NURIASHA BINTI ABD HALIM @ ROBERT
```

Comment: `^[\w\d@&\.-]+`

Comment: just found this one ^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$ look good and allow space in between and no special character

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding for the error, does it means not allow special character for Username?

Not quite - there are six special characters you can use in Domino usernames.  As well as any alphanumeric character (A-Z, 0-9), you can use ampersands (&), apostrophes('), hyphens (-), periods (.), spaces ( ) , and underscores (_).  The at sign (@) is definitely not allowed. (IBM use the phrase "expressly prohibited") ([Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/plan_dominonamingrequirements_c.html))

One other thing to note is that the documentation says there is a limit of 79 characters on a users name, so to be safe it may be worth adding that to any regex you use.

A suitable Java regex for use in an XPage validator might be:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9&-.' _]{1,79}"
```

(Note, I have only tested this on RegexPlanet and not in an XPage.)